# Can we make pda for a^n b^n+1?

Tags: computation-theory

I am little confused about either can we make pda for a^n b^n+1 language ? As to my knowledge pda can be made only for CFL. Does a^n b^n+1 is cfl or not? Plz help

Comment: Is `+` and `1` exact literal/character here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: Yes, n+1 is basicaly the power of b.

Answer (score 0):

The Context free grammar of `a^n b^n+1` would be:

```
S -> aS'bb
S' -> aS'b | empty
```

Since the CFG exists, the PDA is also possible for this language.

Comment: Can you please make it for me?

Comment: Follow the algorithm how to find the PDA for a given CFG. I think this guide will be helpful https://www.cs.unc.edu/~plaisted/comp455/slides/pdacfg3.4.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Given Language : a^n b^(n+1)

It is a Context Free Language Because Context Free Grammar exits.

```
   S -> aS'bb
   S'-> aS'b| epsilon(€)
```

So, we can construct a PDA(Push Down Automata) for it.

PDA for a^n b^(n+1) is

```
  (q0, a, Z0) =(q0,  aZ0) 
  (q0, a, a)  =(q0,  aa) 
  (q0, b, a)  =(q1, €(pop)) 
  (q1, b, a)  =(q1, €(pop)) 
  (q1, b, Z0) =(q2, Z0)
```

Here,  represents transition.
€ represents pop operation.
q0 is the initial state.
q2 is the final state.

whenever, any string in the above language is passed to PDA it reaches final state q2.

If strings not present in above language does not reach q2.hence,those strings are rejected.

examples of strings in the language: a^3b^4 ,a^59b^60 etc.

PDA Image:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPdBP.jpg